# Unknown prop `iconStyle` on <div> tag while using Card/Card-header

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Cannot style the expandalble Icon button
version 0.18.1

This is my code

```
class TaskCard  extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
 }
  render(){
  const {data}=this.props;
  return (
  <Card >
    <CardHeader
      title={this.props.title}
      subtitle= {data.FixDetails}
      actAsExpander={true}
      showExpandableButton={true}
      avatar={
              <div style={{display:'inline'}}>
              <FontIcon className="material-icons" style={{marginRight:'15px'}} >play_arrow</FontIcon>
              <FontIcon className="material-icons" color={getSevrityColor(data.Sevirity)} >error</FontIcon>
              </div>
              }
      style={{display:'inline-block',width:'80%'}}
      iconStyle={{margin:'0px'}}
    />
    <CardActions style={{display:'inline-block'}}>`
//buttons
    </CardActions>
    <CardText expandable={true} >
      {data.FixDetails}
    </CardText>
  </Card>
  )
}`
};
```

which I render through map
`data.Tasks.map((x,i) => <TaskCard  key={i} data={x} Tags={x.Tags} title={x.Tags.origin} subtitle={x.Type}/>)`

The error I get is.I had to add the the arrow in avatar as I was not able to get the IconButton to the left as required.

```
Warning: Unknown prop iconStyle on <div> tag. Remove this prop from the element. For details, 
    in div (created by CardHeader)
    in CardHeader (created by TaskCard)
    in div (created by Card)
    in div (created by Paper)
    in Paper (created by Card)
    in Card (created by TaskCard)
    in TaskCard (created by tasks)
    in div (created by List)
    in List (created by tasks)
    in div (created by tasks)
    in div (created by tasks)
    in div (created by tasks)
    in tasks (created by Unknown)
    in div (created by Page)
    in TweenOne (created by QueueAnim)
    in div (created by QueueAnim)
    in QueueAnim (created by Page)
    in div (created by Page)
    in Page (created by Connect(Page))
    in Connect(Page) (created by DimensionsHOC)
    in div (created by DimensionsHOC)
    in DimensionsHOC (created by Unknown)
    in div (created by MainAppLoggedIn)
    in div (created by MainAppLoggedIn)
    in div (created by MainAppLoggedIn)
    in section (created by MainAppLoggedIn)
    in div (created by MainAppLoggedIn)
    in MainAppLoggedIn (created by DimensionsHOC)
    in div (created by DimensionsHOC)
    in DimensionsHOC (created by BaseDashboard)
    in BaseDashboard (created by Connect(BaseDashboard))
    in Connect(BaseDashboard) (created by Unknown)
    in div (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in MuiThemeProvider (created by App)
    in App (created by Connect(App))
    in Connect(App) (created by Unknown)
    in Unknown (created by Unknown)
    in Unknown
    in Provider
```

The main aim of all this is to make the expandable IconButton appear on the left side instead of right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using old version of this lib, where `iconStyle` is not yet implemented. You can ignore this warning(not an error as you mentioned in question by the way) or just upgrade to current version.

[Property reference for your estimated material-ui version (0.18.1)](http://www.material-ui.com/v0.18.1/#/components/card)

Regarding avatar icons position:
there is an avatar positioning scheme in CardHeader, with image before the title\subtitle block (i.e. to the left), so you need to override this.
Look at [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/j25qm9kq5y) i made, based on your code snippet.

Comment: okay.but what can I do then to get the expandable Iconbutton on the left side instead of the default right side ?

Comment: Why are you asking about propType warnings anyway then? Add an example to let people see what you need to move. This buttons can be moved easily in default material Card setup.

Comment: @ChaitanyaAshtekar edited my answer to include example about icon positioning. Hope that helps.

Comment: pls see https://codesandbox.io/s/3ywp2wwvr5 .I have added comment in MUItest.js.I need to move the showExpandableButton={true} to left

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/p502r97w1j
something like that. Can be achieved with closeIcon\openIcon props even, there are various ways to solve this. You have to edit your question to properly describe what you want to achieve. This is not about `unknown propstyle`, rather about placement of the elements. All your questions are answered in material-ui doc.